# Remove all but certain words from a list (like a white list)

Tags: python, list

Imagine a list that has random words:

```
words = ['elephant', 'dog', 'blue', 'sam', 'white', 'red', 'sun', 'moon']
```

And I want to remove all but the following words (like a whitelist):

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'white']
```

And I want to produce the following list (order matters):

```
filtered = ['blue', 'white', 'red']
```

I've thought about something like this (which works fine):

```
filtered = filter (lambda a: a == 'red' or a == 'green' or a == 'blue' or a == 'orange' or a == 'white', words)
```

But is this really the best / most efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep order and efficiently filter out non-colors, create a `set` of colors, so that `in` checking is faster and then you can just go thru all words and filter out non-colors

```
words = ['elephant', 'dog', 'blue', 'sam', 'white', 'red', 'sun', 'moon']
colors = set(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'white'])
print [word for word in words if word in colors]
```

output:

```
['blue', 'white', 'red']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
words = ['elephant', 'dog', 'blue', 'sam', 'white', 'red', 'sun', 'moon']
filterset = frozenset(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'white'])
filtered = [x for x in words if x in filterset]
```

This solution has the advantage that even for a relatively large `filterset` it will be relatively fast, and it doesn't assume that the `words` list contains only unique entries.

You could leave the `filterset` as just your `filterlist`, but this will hurt performance, especially if the list is large.

Answer (score 1):

```
filtered = filter(lambda a: a in whitelis, words)
```

should do the trick

this can also be written as a list comprehension

```
filtered = [x for x in letters if x in whitelist]
```

as mentioned below, you can use the set type to make sure that every word in the whitelist is unique. This is useful when your whitelist is not hardcoded, but somehow generated, for example from records in a database.

Answer (score 1):

use set operations:

```
words = ['elephant', 'dog', 'blue', 'sam', 'white', 'red', 'sun', 'moon']
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'white']
filtered = set(words).difference(colors)
```

Comment: This approach makes two critical assumptions: 1) That either the `words` list doesn't contain duplicates or that they don't need to be preserved and 2) The order of `filtered` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Although list comprehension are often considered as more pythonic, I do like functional `filter` if we can write it without `lambda`:

```
>> filter(set(colors).__contains__, words)
['blue', 'white', 'red']
```